# Intersection with very ample divisor and linear equivalence

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, cohomology, intersection-theory, divisors

Let $X$ be a smooth, projective variety and $D, E$ two effective divisors of $X$ which correspond to distinct elements on the cohomology group $H^2(X,\mathbb{Q})$. Denote by $H$ a very ample divisor on $X$. Is it then true that $H.D$ and $H.E$ correspond to distinct elements of $H^4(X,\mathbb{Q})$? If not true in general, is there any known condition on $X$ under which this holds true?

**EDIT:** Assume that the underlying field is algebraically closed of characteristic zero and $\dim X \ge 3$.

Comment: That follows by the Hard Lefschetz Theorem (at least in characteristic $0$).

Comment: We'd probably better assume $\dim X \geq 3$.

Comment: @JackHuizenga and JasonStarr: I have edited the question as per your comments. Thanks.